# Python serial data read

Tags: python, arduino

Please help me find problem in this code:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
ser.baudrate=9600
ser1=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
ser1.baudrate=9600
ser2=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",9600)
ser2.baudrate=9600

while True: 

 read_ser=ser.readline()
 read_ser1=ser1.readline()
 read_ser1=ser2.readline()
 print(read_ser)
 print(read_ser1)
 print(read_ser2)
```

I expect that it will show me message from connected Arduino. Arduino send it when I apply card to RFID reader. But, it send only from first ser

Comment: You will probably need to add a timeout option to each `Serial` object, so that your loop doesn't get hung up waiting for a port that currently isn't sending you any data.

Comment: @jasonharper in which place? I tried after just after each read_ser line. But it show me serial data only if I attach card to each Arduino in row like they defined. I want to see data evry time when card attach.

Comment: It's an option to the `Serial()` constructor - see the pyserial docs for all of the options you can specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as I expected

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600,timeout=1)
ser.baudrate=9600
ser1=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600,timeout=1)
ser1.baudrate=9600
ser2=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",9600,timeout=1)
ser2.baudrate=9600
while True: # Run forever

 read_ser=ser.readline()
 if (read_ser != ""):
        print(read_ser)
 read_ser1=ser1.readline()
 if (read_ser1 != ""):
         print(read_ser1)
 read_ser2=ser2.readline()
 if (read_ser2 != ""):
         print(read_ser2)
```

Thank you @jasonharper